# Can't find a running Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to start a new rails server to run my application, however, when I try to run the command it gives me this error:

```
% rails server
=\> Booting Puma
=\> Rails 7.0.4 application starting in development
=\> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
A server is already running. Check /Users/brianliao/Documents/cs166/kiwibefriends/tmp/pids/server.pid.
```

How do I navigate to the directory where the server is running?

Comment: You can use the `cd` command to go to that path and open the `pid` file.

Comment: Also, use the `ps` command to see the server process. And the `kill` command to stop it.

Comment: I'm assuming you are on Linux or Mac. The commands for Windows are different.